# Передача значений из html формы в php

Tags: joomla, php, post, методы

joomla.

Есть форма с просто полями ввода и списками. При передаче через поля ввода все корректно.
При передаче значений из полей со списками - белиберда, не имеющая смысла. Как можно вылечить? ((

Заранее благодарен!

**Дополнено.**

```
<p>Срок действия активированной карточки
<select name="srokrab" size="0">
<option value="”day”">1день</option>
<option value="”month”">месяц</option>
<option value="”thmonth”">3 месяца</option>
<option value="”hyear”">полгода</option>
<option value="”year”">год</option>
<option value="”infinity”">бесконечно</option>
</select>
</p>
```

Затем передаю это в mail.php. Результат от этого поля: `вЂќmonthвЂќ`. У другого списка другие значения, но результат: `вЂќmonthвЂќ`. ((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select name='bar[]' multiple='multiple' rows='5'>
<option value='3'>foo</option>
<option value='7'>foo2</option>
<option value='8'>foo3</option>
<option value='1000'>foo4</option>
</select>
```

В таком случае будет передан массив bar[]. Читать его можно так:
$_REQUEST['bar'][2] - второе значение. При выборе всех элементов списка оно равняется 8

Comment: благодарен, вот только значение multiple отсутствует: просто список с текстовыми значениями, одно из которых необходимо выбрать - вот только при передаче этого значения методом POST - белиберда..... причем одинаковая, что бы ни было выбрано (((

Comment: Value и Name точно заполнено?
Что за билеберда приходит?

Comment: Добавлено в вопрос.

Comment: решил ))) после вашего ответа - просто посмотрел по аналогии и нашел ошибку ))) 
СПАСИБО!

Comment: Вы хоть делитесь, в чем ошибка то была, для будущих поколений.

Answer (score 1):

Моя строка:

```
<option value="”month”">месяц</option>
```

Строка сейчас:

```
<option value="month">месяц</option>
```

А потом уже в ПХП делаю обработку результатов:  если переменная равна "month", присваиваем ей значение "месяц" и т.д.